# Looping a whole program when a desired input comes

Tags: python, loops

I recently started programming in Python and I made a small shop. I want it to ask you if you want to buy anything else, and if the answer is yes, it will loop to the start of the program. I have tried other solutions but none of them worked. I'm using Python 3.x. If you want to take a look here it is:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
hours = now.hour

if hours < 12:
    greeting = "Good morning"
elif hours < 15:
    greeting = "Good afternoon"
elif hours < 18:
    greeting = "Good evening"
elif hours < 24:
    greeting = "Good night"       
print('{}!'.format(greeting),)

a = input('would you like to buy a console? (y/n) ')

if a == 'y':                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    consoleQ = input('What console would you like? (ps4/switch/xboxone) ')
    if consoleQ == 'ps4':
        print('Ok! Here is your Ps4! Have a good day!')
    elif consoleQ == 'xboxone':
        print('Ok! Here is your Xbox One! Have a good day!')
    elif consoleQ == 'switch':
        print('Ok! Here is your Switch! Have a good day!')   
        exit(print('Have a {}!'.format(greeting),))

elif a == 'n':
    print('Okay, have a good day!')
    exit()
```

I have tried using this to loop: (didn't work)

```
loop = input('Would you like anything else? (y/n)')

while loop == 'y':
    a = input('Would you like to buy a console? (y/n)')
```

I have just started, so please don't be harsh. I know that I don't REALLY know a lot of stuff, after all, this is my second week programming. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) topic should be very useful. You just need to adjust from "user did give wrong input" to "user wants to continue".

Comment: Duplicated question!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
while True:
    do_something()
    loop = input("Would you like to buy anything else? (y/n)")
    if loop != 'y':
        break # Break out of loop if not answered yes
    # else, continue looping
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill be shure to try this out!

Answer (score 0):

Because your loop variable is set outside the loop, if the user answers yes the first time, it will loop forever. Try putting the loop input inside the while loop.

```
loop = input('Would you like anything else? (y/n) ')

while loop == 'y':
    a = input('Would you like to buy a console? (y/n) ')
    #Do all the buying a console stuff in the middle here
    loop = input('Would you like anything else? (y/n) ')
```